# Заполнение массива

Tags: массивы, c

При инициализации массив можно заполнить так:

```
int m_0[20]={4,6,9,1,0,23,10,4,22,80,11,23,7,3,2,16,11,1,0,20};
```

Как можно заполнить массив этим же значениями после инициализации? Значения элементов поменялись, и нужно значения "сбросить" к дефолтным.

Так не прокатывает:

```
 m_0[]={4,6,9,1,0,23,10,4,22,80,11,23,7,3,2,16,11,1,0,20}
```

Comment: Хм

     static int m_0_def[] = {4,6,9,1,0,23,10,4,22,80,11,23,7,3,2,16,11,1,0,20};
     ...
     for(i=0; i < sizeof m_0_def/sizeof(int); i++) m_0[i] = m_0_def[i];

Ну или 

     memcpy(m_0, m_0_def, sizeof m_0_def);

Comment: Синхрон :-)

Comment: @klopp, @alexlz: great minds think alike. +1.

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov, IMHO средствами языка - никак.

Только ручками. Что то вроде

    int *copy = malloc(sizeof(m_0)); // запомним все значения
    memcpy(copy, m_0, sizeof(m_0));
    .....
    .....
    memcpy(m_0, copy, sizeof(m_0)); // восстановим все значения

Ну, тут еще можно кучу макросов на разные вкусы наваять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static int array_template[] = {4,6,9,1,0,23,10,4,22,80,11,23,7,3,2,16,11,1,0,20};
void update_array( int * target )
{
  for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array_template)/sizeof(array_template[0]); i++ )
  {
    target[i] = array_template[i];
  } 
}
```

Ну или `memcpy()`

Comment: `memcpy` выглядит посишнее как-то.

Comment: Ну, то есть, задать массив-пример. А в нужный копировать его значения?
Т.е. просто задать все значения массиву нельзя, так?

Comment: Эти значения всё равно надо где-то хранить. Безымянные константные массивы (в отличие от многочисленных диалектов паскаля -- виртовский не входит) -- не предусмотрены. Поэтому надо использовать имя.